# Equivalent of WMI Win32_Process field for Process.PrivateMemorySize64?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi

When using WMI, which is the equivalent member in the [Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for [Process.PrivateMemorySize64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) property?. I see various memory fields but I'm not sure which of them is the right one.

This question is about a specific WMI class usage in .NET regardless the language, however I understand the question I did is too short so I just want to share this code example written in VB.NET to get an idea of what I would like to realize with WMI:

```vb
Dim scope As New ManagementScope("root\CIMV2")
Dim query As New SelectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where ProcessId = '{0}'", pId))
Dim options As New EnumerationOptions With {.ReturnImmediately = True, .DirectRead = True}

Using wmi As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query, options)
    Using obj As ManagementObject = wmi.Get().Cast(Of ManagementObject).Single()
        Dim memSize As ULong = CULng(obj.Properties("PrivateMemorySize?").Value)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: It is PrivatePageCount.  Bad description btw, it is bytes, not pages.  WMI tends to be wonky.

Comment: Thankyou as always for your help @Hans Passant.